# Mounting /var /tmp /var/log to separate partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, redhat-enterprise-linux

Per DISA hardening requirements for RHEL, I'm supposed to make sure a number of locations on the filesystem are mounted on separate partitions.  A few of the locations they specify include /var /tpm /var/log etc.  Is it possible to go about doing this on a live machine (without booting a separate OS)?  And how would I go about doing that.  I've backed up the OS so if I do screw something up I can recover. Thanks!

Comment: We can't give you specific instructions unless we know your setup. Could you [edit] your question to include your `/etc/fstab`?

Answer (score 1):

Just... mount them:
`# mount /dev/sdxy /var/log`
and add them to `/etc/fstab`

Before it, you can mount it on, say `/mnt` and here create directory structure, then mount it at final destination